# Сравнение потоков в elrang и c#

Tags: c#, многопоточность, erlang

Сейчас есть 1000 потоков в c#, которые запускаются, выполняются, закрываются за 1 минуту
То есть в секунду получается около 16 потоков.

Компьютер:

1. i7
2. 4 реальных ядра
3. 4 виртуальных ядра

При работе программы загруженность всех ядер до 30-49%

Вопрос. Что получим с потоками на elrang? Аналогичную ситуацию 16 потоков в секунду
или erlang сможет это число потоков в секунду увеличить? Или имеем здесь физическую ограниченность на ядра, то есть в среднем где то 2(4) C# thread на 1(2) ядра процессора?

Comment: Насколько я знаю ерланг тем и отличается что он не упирается в огронечения системы и потоков можно плодить пока память не кончится. Так как все это крутится на виртуальной машине erlang`а и нет привязки к желези или ОС.

Comment: Что это у вас за приложение такое в котором 1000 потоков?? У меня всего в данный момент 485 потоков запущено - и это во всей операционке!

Comment: @prog432, а что каждый поток делает и какую задачу они все вместе решают?

Без понимания этой "кухни" ничего определенного сказать невозможно.

Comment: Ну вообще ерланг расчитан не на 1000 потоков, а на милион и больше. Также он позволяет собирать кластерные системы и брать на себя всю рутину взаимодействия. Для прогера это одна мультисистема с потоками. На нем пишутся высоконагруженные конкурентные системы. Поэтому это точно не для десктопа, хотя некоторые [извращаются](http://www.wings3d.com/). Ну это я для справки, и как бы там c# рядом не стоит... слишком уж узкая специализация Erlang`a. При высоких нагрузках даже Java проигрывает.

Comment: @prog432, Пожалуйста, оформляйте вопросы согласно правилам сообщества, иначе они будут удаляться.

Answer (score 2):

Потоки в Erlang нельзя напрямую сравнивать с потоками операционной системы, используемой в Java

В Erlang реализована концепция легковесных потоков ([green threads](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green_threads)). При этом в действительности эмулятор может использовать гораздо меньшее число потоков операционной системы.

Концептуальная разница состоит в том, что в erlang поток, или как его в местной терминологии назвают, процесс создается под небольшую задачу, которую он решает. Таким образом, каждый процесс обрабатывает приходящие сообщения с использованием внутреннего состояния. Erlang таким образом реализует [модель акторов](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C_%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2).

Сравнивать процессы erlang нужно с [акторами](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2186222/774651) на C#.

Потоки операционной системы обычно не создают в таком большом количестве. В случае использования потоков для ускорения вычислений их число обычно выбирают таким образом, чтобы обеспечить необходимый уровень нагрузки. В простейшем случае, если потоки не простаивают в ожидании, и необходимо полностью утилизировать ресурсы системы, число потоков выбирается равным числу ядер процессора. Для выполнения большого числа задач в этом случае пользуются пулом потов (thread pool). Задачи распределяются по этому пулу потоков, при этом потоки не перезапускаются.

Легкие потоки удается создавать в гораздо большем количестве, потому что в их случае среда выполнения полностью контролирует поток и может прерывать его в заранее определенных местах, таким образом издержки на синхронизацию, сохранение и восстановление состояния потока сильно уменьшаются по сравнению с потоками операционной системы.

Answer (score 1):

Начнём с того, что раз у вашей машины 8 ядер, то физически распараллелить вычисление более чем на 8 потоков вы не сможете, вне зависимости от языка. Если вы создадите более 8 потоков, некоторые из них будут простаивать (и scheduler операционной системы будет следить за тем, чтобы потоки простаивали более-менее равномерно).

Затем, запуск одновременно 1000 потоков — очень неоптимальное решение для современного C#. Запуск потока — дорогая операция. Если вам нужно параллельное выполнение тысячи *вычислений*, лучше представить их в виде `Task`'ов, и запустить параллельно: TPL позаботится о том, чтобы выполнить их, не создавая ненужных дополнительных потоков. Для этого вам придётся сделать что-то наподобие

```
await Task.WhenAll(dataArray.Select(d => Task.Run(Compute(d)));
```

или воспользоваться [`Parallel.For`](http://www.albahari.com/threading/part5.aspx#_The_Parallel_Class).

Потоки Эрланга делают (примерно) то же, что и `Task`'и C#.

---

А если ваши задания занимаются вводом-выводом или общением с асинхронными источниками информации, то выгоды от перехода на `Task`'и и async/await ещё больше: простаивающие задания будут вовсе не занимать при этом *никакого* потока!